# Client side form validation in mvc4

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

can i validate email and password  using jquery.

i am using the following codes for validation . but this is not working

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class = "emlfrm" }))
 {
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)  
     <p>@Html.Label("Email")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Mem_Email, new { @class = "eml" })
        <label id="error" style="padding:0;color:red;font-size:12px; width:100%;"></label>

     </p>
     <p style="padding:0 20px;">
        @Html.Label("Password")
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mem_PWD)

     </p>
    <p style="margin-left:27%;">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>

    }


$(function () {
$(window).on('load', function () {
    $(".emlfrm").on("submit", function () {

       //email validation
        var x = $(this).find(".eml").eq(0).val();
        var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
        var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
        if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
            $("#error").html("Not a valid Email address.");
        return false;
        }
    });
});
```

This is not show any error message.

Comment: do check if the scripts file needed are loaded properly in the layout page before the loading of this register page.

Comment: What does "but this is not working " mean ? The form gets posted ? An error is shown in the console ? Have you tried to console.log in your load and submit handler to see if the handlers get registered ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following in your web.config file:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
```

If it is not there add it - it should be added to `<appSettings>` section.